# Can't Read Files in Sdcard in emulator

Tags: android, file-io, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I have some problems in my App.

I just wanna read file in sdcard, so I put the file in /storage/sdcard/abcd (the folder I made by adb) in emulator.
File name is "1.14P", and I verify it is in that path. Its permission is 770.

But my problem is, I can't access sdcard by Application.

```
sampleFile = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "abcd/1.14P");
sampleFile.exists()                     //return false

sampleFile2 = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tttt");
sampleFile2.mkdir()                  //return false
```

Sdcard is mounted well, I thought.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();    //return "mounted"
```

I give the permission but I can't access to sdcard. Here is my manifest.xml. (part)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hu.test004" >
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...(Activities)
```

I can't understand why it happens. Please give me some favor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED::I've got it!
The problem is, I declared permissions in capital letter, so App doesn't grant permissions.

I change

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and permission granted.

Thank you for your favor all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "," is part of the problem. The other is the "exists()" is for directories, not files.

See here:

[new File(path) always actually creates a file on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948236/new-filepath-always-actually-creates-a-file-on-android)

contrary to the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

you may want to use `isFile()` instead.

Comment: I doubt the problem is not about the code, but about emulator or sdcard setting, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding "/" in front of your names??
e.g. "/abcd/1.14P"

Comment: API code fix the '/' problem, so it doesn't matter.